# Use ASP.NET when creating Windows 8 App

Tags: asp.net

Hi i just wonder if I could use ASP.NET to create a Windows 8 App or is ASP.NET only for homepages?

Comment: S u can use ASP.NET to create Windows 8 APP.

Comment: homepages? did you meant web sites maybe?

Comment: yeah sorry i'm from sweden we call websites "hemsidor" (homepages)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is for creating web applications.

To create win 8 app you can use any language supported by Microsoft (vb.net, c++, c#, javascript and others) along with XAML (Extensible Application Markup Language) or plain HTML.

Although I think you can create a web app in asp.net and then open in inside win 8 app in browser mode (insane!).